# How can I determine whether a Windows XP cmd variable ends with a given string?

Tags: windows-xp, command-line, environment-variables

I want to check on whether the last character(s) of an environment variable are `\` or `.exe`. How can I do this in Windows XP SP3?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To use substrings:

```
set _parm1=foo.exe
if [%_parm1:~-1%]==[\] echo ends with \
if /i [%_parm1:~-4%]==[.exe] echo ends with .exe
```

You replace the number before the % sign to alter how many characters it checks at the end of the string.

Comment: It pays to read the help on all the cmd commands, especially set and for.  They were improved tremendously in XP.  While the syntax isn't easy to remember or easy to maintain when someone else created it, it will help you accomplish things when you are forced to do it with a batch file.  It works on every windows system since XP, so it is something good to know.

Answer (score 3):

Don't do it, for your own sanity. Switch to PowerShell, Perl, Python, C#... even VBScript is acceptable.

---

```
:: call the subroutine defined below...
call :check "%somevariable%"
:: and check its exit code
if %ERRORLEVEL% equ 0 (
    echo Yes
) else (
    echo No
)

goto :eof

:check
    if "%~nxi"=="" exit /b 0
    :: do a case-insensitive check because Windows would accept ".EXE"
    :: and ".Exe", so we should too.
    if /i "%~xi"==".exe" exit /b 0
    exit /b 1
```

For comparison, equivalent Python code:

```
if somevar.endswith("\\") or somevar.lower().endswith(".exe"):
    print("Yes")
else:
    print("No")
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you trying to do this programatically or just once?

If you want to see an environment variable once, typing `echo %variablename%` will work.

If you're trying to do it programatically, you'll probably need to use VBScript or soemthing similar to do the required string manipulation. There should be an example in the [MS Script Repository](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/) that can get you started, depending on exactly what you're looking to do with the variable once you isolate it.